# Easiest way to implement Watson Language translation to Watson Assistant?

Tags: language-translation, watson-assistant

I'd like to know the easiest way to integrate IBM Language Translation to my current IBM Watson Assistant. I think I can do it through Cloud Functions, but I'm not sure how.

I already read the GitHub Sample Watson app, but it wasn't clear to me how ti implement it.

Comment: I would recommend asking on Slack as it is more of a discussion: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can indeed use a Webhook for your use case.

You can put the URL of the Language Translator-Service (e.g. https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v3/translate?version=2018-05-01) as URL of your Webhook within watson assistant.

You can find an example in the docs [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks):